# Laravel Eloquent model events

Tags: laravel, events

I want to handle eloquent events. If i register a listener for a wildcard event 'eloquent.*' the handler callback takes, as parameter, the model instance that fired the event.

How can i find out the exact event that was fired?

Thanks in advance.

PS: i'm using Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is available from the dispatcher via its [`firing()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.html#method_firing) method.

Using the Event facade, you'd call `Event::firing()`.